# How to convert column data type string to the date (not datetime) using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to convert whole column which has data type string to the date. The following script gives a datetime data type, but I need just a date. May I ask about help?

```
df['date_of_birth'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_birth'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Thanks

Comment: pandas datetime does not handle date and time separately (as you could do in native Python). If you want to floor to the date, add `.dt.floor('d')`. That will set the time to zero / 00:00:00.

Comment: Or `.dt.normalize()`